# anchor tag disrupting css layout of slideshow

Tags: html, css

I am currently working on a practice e-commerce site, as part of a project.

I am adding anchor tags around images which are part of a slideshow. However what I a finding is that as soon as I add the anchor tags, it changes the layout of the image in the slideshow and they are not longer the size to fit within the slideshow container. Part of the image is chopped off.

Have a look at the screen shots below, showing what it looks like before adding the anchor tags and then after.

My HTML and CSS code is also shown below.

**Before adding anchor tag (How I want the image to remain size-wise with anchor tags)**
[image]

**After adding anchor tags**
[image]

HTML code:

```
<div class="homepage-slider">
    <a href="moreinfo/product6.html"><img src="images/hero-banner/mfprotein.jpg" alt="Protein Deals" /></a>
    <a href="moreinfo/product34.html"><img src="images/hero-banner/plant-protein.jpg" alt="Protein Deals" />
    <a href="moreinfo/product2.html"><img src="images/hero-banner/image5.jpg" alt="Protein Deals" /></a>
    <a href="moreinfo/product45.html"><img src="images/hero-banner/imaged3.jpg" alt="Protein Deals" /></a>
    <a href="moreinfo/product19.html"><img src="images/hero-banner/mfprotein.jpg" alt="Protein Deals" /></a>
</div>
```

CSS CODE:
/*------------------------------------HOME PAGE BANNER SECTION----------------------------------*/

```
#homepage-banner {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    justify-content: space-around;
    height: 82vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.homepage-slider img {
    display: inline-block;
}

.homepage-slider {
    top: 3.5em;
    width: 500%;
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    animation: 24s slider infinite;
}
```

Comment: Missing an </a> here `<a href="moreinfo/product34.html"><img src="images/hero-banner/plant-protein.jpg" alt="Protein Deals" /></a>`

Comment: Right click -> inspect, and identify the style override that's influencing them differently inherited from the anchor tag as parent.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] - you can click edit and then create a snippet using the `[<>]` button. It highlights the code and clicking tidy often shows the syntax errors clearly

Answer (score 0):

By replacing % with vw, it should force the images to fit the container.

```css
#homepage-banner {
  width: 100vw; // from % to vw
  position: relative;
  justify-content: space-around;
  height: 82vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.homepage-slider img {
  width: 100vw; // from % to vw
  display: inline-block;
}

.homepage-slider {
  top: 3.5em;
  width: 500vw; // from % to vw
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-animation: 24s slider infinite;
          animation: 24s slider infinite;
}
```

```html
<div id="homepage-banner">
  <div class="homepage-slider">
    <a href="moreinfo/product6.html"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1538370621607-4919ce7889b3?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=5e6ce231bf8fa9c6125a08389840e7d7&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2249&q=80" alt="Protein Deals" /></a>
    <a href="moreinfo/product34.html"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1538370621607-4919ce7889b3?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=5e6ce231bf8fa9c6125a08389840e7d7&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2249&q=80" /></a>
    <a href="moreinfo/product2.html"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1538370621607-4919ce7889b3?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=5e6ce231bf8fa9c6125a08389840e7d7&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2249&q=80" alt="Protein Deals" /></a>
    <a href="moreinfo/product45.html"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1538370621607-4919ce7889b3?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=5e6ce231bf8fa9c6125a08389840e7d7&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2249&q=80" alt="Protein Deals" /></a>
    <a href="moreinfo/product19.html"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1538370621607-4919ce7889b3?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=5e6ce231bf8fa9c6125a08389840e7d7&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2249&q=80" alt="Protein Deals" /></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What did you add? And you are missing an `</a>`